# Profile shows "upvoted 0 times" in collapsed reputation break down

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I first noticed it at Superuser and checked at Stackoverflow after that. 
If you go to your profile, open the reputation tab and collapse an upvote into several lines,
the Alt-text for the new upvotes is "answer was upvoted 0 times".

[image: Link to screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a glitch in the event count on this specific path where it was being yield returned before it had a chance to set.  In the next build you'll see the correct `"answer was upvoted"` for single votes and `"answer was upvoted N times"` for multiple.